# SQL -Place 2 decimal places in a runtime select -SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, decimal

I have this select query  :

```
SELECT Nombre, Tipo, Descripcion,Abierto,Cerrado, Latitud, Longitud,
SQRT( POW( 69.1 * ( Latitud - 19.55385 ) , 2 ) 
+ POW( 69.1 * ( - 99.21716 - Longitud ) 
* COS( Latitud / 57.3 ) , 2 ) ) AS distance
FROM Clientes
```

It works ok, but it sometimes returns a really long number (many decimal places) and I would like it to return the value with a decimal point with just two places.

I allready tried

```
CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),distance)
```

but I think my code is badly written.
It would be much appreciated if someone could give me an example or something!

Sorry for my english, I hope it's understandable. And thanks in advance!!

Comment: There's nothing wrong with casting it as such. The other option is you could use the `ROUND()` function (e.g. `round(distance, 2)`). Alternatively, (and probably the *best* option) is to have the number formatting in the display layer, rather than in SQL.

Comment: You need to apply the cast on the calculation: `CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),SQRT( POW( 69.1 * ( Latitud - 19.55385 ) , 2 ) 
+ POW( 69.1 * ( - 99.21716 - Longitud ) 
* COS( Latitud / 57.3 ) , 2 ) ))`

Comment: @Xedni: This is not *formatting*, thus it should be done in SQL, not the presentation layer.

Comment: What error did you get when you tried the CONVERT in your question?

Comment: @dnoeth 
This is the error if i try to convert like that:
Query failed: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECIMAL(10,2),SQRT( POW( 69.1 * ( Latitud - ) , 2 ) + POW( 69.1 * ( - Longit' at line 2

Comment: @Xedni i thought the same, but i would like to select several registers, and with the numbers so large i fear that i would be a problem in a long term

the round funcition i would have to apply it after the select statment and before the "From"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the function `Round()` to mathematical round and `Cast` to adjust the precision

Ex:

`select Cast(ROUND(- 99.2171600000009669 ,2) as decimal(10,2))`

Result

```
-99.22
```

In your query:

```
 SELECT Nombre, Tipo, Descripcion,Abierto,Cerrado, Latitud, Longitud,
 Cast(ROUND(SQRT( POW( 69.1 * ( Latitud - 19.55385 ) , 2 ) 
+ POW( 69.1 * ( - 99.21716 - Longitud ) 
* COS( Latitud / 57.3 ) , 2 ) ) ,2) as decimal(10,2)) AS distance
FROM Clientes 
Order By Distance Desc
```

Comment: Worked Perfectly! 
Thanks!

Comment: No problem. :). I edited the response to order by distance desc